# C# WPF MVVM, Getting two instances of main object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am completely new to WPF and MVVM, I am trying to link a property to a textbox on a WPF form. However, I seem to be getting two instances of the main object, which causes -1 exit error. I think this is caused by the class and DataContext dependencies in the XAML file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this might be?

The main part of my XAML includes:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="MyProg.MainWindowViewModel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProg"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProg"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="572" Width="855" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >

    <Window.Resources>
            <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=viewModel}">
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
                Text="{Binding FormTextBox}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My Model includes:

```
namespace MyProg
{
    public class MyProgModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _textBox;     // holds contents of text box

        public string MyTextBox
        {
            get { return _textBox; }

            set
            {
                _textBox = value;
                Console.WriteLine(_textBox);
                OnPropertyChanged("MyTextBox");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Keyboard Model OnPropertyChanged {0}", propertyName);

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and View Model:

```
namespace MyProg
{
    public partial class MyProg : Window,  INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MyProgModel _mainWindowModel;

        private string _textBox = "Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster"; // holds contents of text box

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _mainWindowModel = new MyProgModel
            { // Instantiate and initialise _mainWindowModel
                MyTextBox = "Hello from me"
            };
        }

        public string FormTextBox
        {
            get { return _textBox; }

            set
            {
                _textBox = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FormTextBox");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("View model OnPropertyChanged {0}", propertyName);

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your view model class to be called `MainWindowViewModel` , not `MyProg`?

Comment: Can you compile this code partial class MyProg  and x:Class="MyProg.MainWindowViewModel?

Comment: What is a "-1 exit error"? Please provide the exception message you're getting and at which line exactly.

Comment: @Rostech, yes, sorry, I have had to cut out quite a lot of code and anonymise the names a little, so that type has crept in.

Comment: @Rekshino, Yes it compiles and runs. On first run the text 'Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster' does appear on the form, but no further updates do. I think this is due to the two class instantiations.

Comment: @dymanoid, When running in VS I have to end the program using the Stop button as closing the window does not teminate the program. VS reports: The program '[8364] MyProg.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: @Chris, I would suggest you to read more about exceptions and debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: This isn't mvvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewmodel is simultaneously a view - separate them, otherwise you have a reversive call in window resources(that you need for DataContext)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the link you provided was very useful. I got the original structure for the from the book Pro XAML with C#, and obviously got a few wires crossed.